# Can transaction be stuck in the 'processing' stage and has not been mined by the Blockchain network?

Tags: transactions

Can transaction be stuck in the 'processing' stage and has not been mined by the Blockchain network and due to this, it cannot reflect in wallet ?

My friend send me a bit coin but it did not reach me, Can it get stuck in the

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the fee is not enough then it can take days and then it will be canceled.